# Proton K or M altitude at Max-Q

Tags: launch-vehicle, roscosmos, max-q

I'm trying to fill out a sketch table as part of a research project, and I've run into a bit of a snag. Hopefully someone here can help me out.

I'd like to know the altitude of the Proton K or M vehicle design as it crosses Max-Q.

My Tsiolkovsky calculations went way wrong somehow, and my guesstimation based on raw thrust and launch weight don't seem quite right; I come up with 54,000 ft. or 16.5 km, higher than any of the other major vehicles for which I have hard numbers or good approximations.